# Instead of making the mouse postion to float it makes it to a int PyAutoGui

Tags: python, pyautogui

**PyAutoGui**
its adding in point and making it an int instead of an float, I might just be stupid. This is my first time trying out this libary, the error is coming from Point(x=1558, y=287) and if I try to use it in a screenshot code I just get an error like this float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Point

```
from platform import release
import pytesseract
import pyautogui
import time
import pyautogui
from pynput.mouse import Listener

test = pyautogui.position()
print(test)
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        x = pyautogui.position()
        print(x)
    if release:
        y = pyautogui.position()
        print(y)
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x,y, 100, 100))
    
    if not pressed:
        return False
        
    with Listener(
            on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: `pyautogui.position` returns a tuple of integers (x and y pixel coordinates). What is the issue?

Comment: *Why* are you calling `position()`?  What do you think the `x` and `y` parameters being passed to your listener function might contain?

Comment: When I print test the output is "Point(x=1558, y=287)" and if I try to use it in a screenshot code I just get an error like this "float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Point'"

Comment: Ah, that's your question then. [Edit] your question to include the screenshot attempt and the full stack trace of the resulting error. (Also what's the the extra indentation? That would raise a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Thanks for the tips, but am not really sure why its happening, when I searched up on it everyone else just had the floats not point

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on here:

- You have a lot of unnecessary imports. (Maybe you're using them elsewhere, but you don't need to include them in your question if they're not used in the code you're showing.)
- `pyautogui.position()` returns a tuple of two coordinates. When you set `x =  pyautogui.position()` or `y = pyautogui.position()`, you may have *named* the variable `x` or `y`, but it still contains a tuple of two values. This is what causes your immediate error: internally, the screenshot code tries to convert whatever it gets to a float, and it can't do that with a tuple of two numbers. (It doesn't matter that those two numbers are integers.)
- Your `on_click` function will already be given an x and y coordinate from `pynput`. You've already named them appropriately in the function definition. Just use that, instead of calling `pyautogui.position()` at all.
- Your `with Listener` code is currently indented inside your `on_click` function, which would mean it is never executed.
- You check `released` variable which has never been defined, which would raise a `NameError`.

I think you want to do this:

```
from pyautogui import screenshot
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    # Only take a screenshot when a button is pressed, not also when
    # it's released.
    if pressed:
        im = screenshot(region=(x, y, 100, 100))
        # Then presumably save the screenshot somewhere?

# Back to zero indentation, so this is outside the on_click function
# definition.
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```